# how to build neovim with visual statio2013

Tags: neovim

this is the project home
https://github.com/neovim/neovim

i'm try to use cmake to build it,but failed  .
Do you have any success,tell me the detail way.
thank you!
[image: the screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the master branch of Neovim does not build in Windows.

There is an issue for [Windows support#1749](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1749) with an open [pull request#810](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/810). However the terminal support in that branch is currently broken.

In that first link you can find some instructions on how to build, and a list of issues that still need fixing for Windows support.